# Sails.JS pass data from the view to the controller

Tags: javascript, controller, sails.js

in Sails.js, I am trying to pass the role/mentor key/value pair to be received by the contoller function '/select'

VIEW.ejs

```
  ...
  $.post( '/select', {role: 'mentor'} );
  ...
```

CONTROLLER

```
select: function(req, res) {
    var printRole = req.param('role');
    return res.send("The role is: " + printRole); 
}
```

So far the result I receive on the screen is : The role is **Undefined**
please help

Comment: Need more information. I would post your config/routes.js, your complete view and your complete controller and put it in a gist or a pastbin.

Answer (score 1):

I think param should be plural as in `var printRole = req.params('role')`